How to Fix Render Error when Knitting to HTML in R Markdown
I am starting to learn how to use R Markdown. I opened a new R Markdown file, selected "Restart R and Run All Chunks", and tried knitting to HTML without changing any of the default text or code chunks. I do not get any errors when running the code, but when I try to knit to HTML, I get the below error. What could be causing this error?
|........                                                   |  14%
processing file: test.Rmd
|..................................                         |  57% [cars]    Error in render():
! unused arguments (visible = TRUE, envir = parent.frame())
Backtrace:

rmarkdown::render("C:/Users/Josh/Downloads/test.Rmd", encoding = "UTF-8")
knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
knitr:::process_file(text, output)
knitr:::process_group(group)
knitr:::call_block(x)
...
evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
knitr:::knit_print.default(x, ...)
evaluate (local) normal_print(x)

Quitting from lines 18-19 [cars] (test.Rmd)
Execution halted
I tried reinstalling the rmarkdown package, but that did not change anything.

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete and runnable code aka Rmd and a snippet of your input data if required shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Hi, could you please describe the contents of your Rmd file, where are you running this session and output of your sessionInfo().

if you use renv and or Projects could you try knitting a test.Rmd outside project folder?

I had the same issue, I solved it by updating the package {evaluate} to 1.0.0.
(There were other packages also, but that should be it)

I had the same exact problem. In my case I had to update all packages. After that, everything worked again.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
