Default RMarkdown html doc failed to build Error in render()
Long time reader of resolved issues, but first time posting!
I teach on a course that uses RStudio, including writing documents using RMarkdown. However, out of 200+ students I have one who has a very unusual issue that I just don't know how to resolve. FYI, this seems to be the same issue as posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79029644/how-to-fix-render-error-when-knitting-to-html-in-r-markdown.
It is hard to demonstrate a minimal reproducible example because this error is created for the default RMarkdown HTML file. I've tried a few temporary remedies but I have no idea what might be root cause.
Detailed steps:

Create an R project.
Start a new R Markdown document, File > New File > R Markdown...
In the new window, select 'Document' and then 'HTML' as the default Output Format. Keep all other options as the default values and press 'ok'. (Note, the same render issue is also generated for a pdf document)
Save the document in the working directory and click the 'knit' button.

The document fails to build with the following output under the Render tab:
|.................                                          |  29% \[setup\]

processing file: test.Rmd
|..................................                         |  57% \[cars\]    Error in `render()`:
! unused arguments (visible = TRUE, envir = parent.frame())
Backtrace:

 1. rmarkdown::render(...)
 2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
 3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
 4. knitr:::process_group(group)
 5. knitr:::call_block(x)
    ...
 6. evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
 7. knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
 8. knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
 9. knitr:::knit_print.default(x, ...)
10. evaluate (local) normal_print(x)

Quitting from lines 19-20 \[cars\] (test.Rmd)
Execution halted

Below presents the version and session information on the student's computer:
> version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          4.1                              
year           2024                             
month          06                               
day            14                               
svn rev        86737                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
nickname       Race for Your Life               

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rmarkdown_2.28  lubridate_1.9.3 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.1   dplyr_1.1.4    
 [6] purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.5     tidyr_1.3.1     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.5.1  
[11] tidyverse_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.5      compiler_4.4.1    tidyselect_1.2.1  scales_1.3.0      fastmap_1.2.0    
 [6] R6_2.5.1          generics_0.1.3    knitr_1.48        munsell_0.5.1     pillar_1.9.0     
[11] tzdb_0.4.0        rlang_1.1.4       utf8_1.2.4        stringi_1.8.4     xfun_0.47        
[16] timechange_0.3.0  cli_3.6.3         withr_3.0.1       magrittr_2.0.3    digest_0.6.37    
[21] grid_4.4.1        rstudioapi_0.16.0 hms_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.4   vctrs_0.6.5      
[26] evaluate_0.24.0   glue_1.7.0        fansi_1.0.6       colorspace_2.1-1  tools_4.4.1      
[31] pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.8.1

I tried a few simple things to try to resolve the issue and all of the problems seemed to be related to rendering the results of the R chunk on lines 17-19:
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

From playing around to try to diagnose the issue, I found that the error may be related to markdown failing to render output from the default printing option when simply typing the name of an object. For example, if I replace the above code chunk with the following (a simple assignment) then this works:
x <- 1

But if I ask R to show me the content of x (as demonstrated below) then the knit fails with the above render error message.
x <- 1
x

However, if I explicitly use the print() command as demonstrated below, then the document correctly knits.
x <- 1
print(x)

Unfortunately I have no clue what is causing this problem as this is a very strange an unique issue for 1 student out of 200+ students. Any ideas about what is happening or any suggestions about how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Simon Taylor (he/him)

Does running knitr::knit("test.Rmd") return the same error? What version of RStudio is the person running (you've only shown the version for R itself)?  What this student an R user before the class? Any chance they have an .Rprofile file in their home directory?


Student not an R user
RStudio 2024.09.0+375 "Cranberry Hibiscus" Release (c8fc7aee6dc218d5687553f9041c6b1e5ea268ff, 2024-09-16) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2024.09.0+375 Chrome/124.0.6367.243 Electron/30.4.0 Safari/537.36, Quarto 1.5.57
I ran
knit("test.Rmd")
markdownToHTML("test.md", output="test.html")
Ran without errors, but test.html contains an error msg under the relevant chunk about unused params
No .Rprofile file


dir(getwd())
[1] "figure" "test.html" "test.md" "test.Rmd" "test_knit.Rproj"

